# Serving Firebase Functions doesn't hot reload on Windows

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, watchman, hot-reload

Serving Firebase Functions locally with the [firebase serve](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) command is supposed to enable hot reloading but this doesn't seem to work on windows, even with [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#download-for-windows-beta) installed. Is there a better solution aside from running `npm build` after each code change?

Comment: If the CLI doesn't work the way you expect, then file a bug report.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: did and an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/758#issuecomment-441775681) was reopened

Answer (score 27):

I mixed the 2 answers:

```json
"scripts": {
   "serve": "npm run build -- --watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions",
   ...
}
```

Comment: This solution caused crashes for me, using two separate terminals worked.

Answer (score 14):

I do it the following way (additionally to galki`s answer):

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

and in another terminal tab I just use

```
npm run build -- --watch
```

from within functions directory. This way you have some kind of faster dev cycle.

Answer (score 8):

To enable **hot reloading** on firebase functions with typescript you can add this 2 commands to your package.json file

```
"build:watch": "tsc -w"
"serve:watch": "npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions",
```

If you want also to use **path aliases** feature **you will be required to install 2 additional dev packages** in order to make it work

```
npm install --save-dev tsc-alias concurrently
```

[tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) is for replacing alias paths with relative paths after typescript compilation of tsc compiler because the compiler alone can't resolve the alias paths

[concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) is for runing multiple commands concurrently

After installing the 2 packages you will need to **add this 2 scripts** to your **package.json** file

```
"build:watch": "concurrently --kill-others \"tsc -w\" \"tsc-alias -w\"",
"serve:watch": "npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions",
```

Starting of **development with hot reload** then will be as easy as running only in the terminal

```
npm run serve:watch
```

**Please Note:**
I am using this versions of the packages

```
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.1",
"firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
"tsc-alias": "^1.5.0",
"typescript": "^4.5.5",
"concurrently": "^7.0.0",
```

Older or newer versions might introduce some issues with compiling the code

Answer (score 4):

Try following npm script

```
"serve": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc --watch | firebase serve --only functions"
```

Answer (score 1):

It works as of the current point in time (firebase-tools 8.0.0).

Both

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

and

```
 firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

work but one still needs to run `npm run build` manually each time.